# Python HttpConnection redirect 301/307 error

Tags: python, redirect

[image]

Hey guys. As you can see for some reason its giving me an issue with a 307 redirect error, sometimes it gives me a 301 moved permanently error also.

I'm assuming this is because it expects the url without the https:// possibly. But I cant add that to the constructor of the HttpConnection because it thinks whatever is after the ':' is the port.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting an `http` connection with `reddit` and `reddit` is redirecting to `https` version of the website. Moreover, you are trying to make a `POST` request through insecure `HTTP` connection, which makes no sense. You can use [httplib.HTTPSConnection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection). A better approach would be handling redirections programmatically, so your program doesn't stop just because of redirection.